# Issue in finding smallest and nearest prime number in this program

Tags: python, string, list, ascii

My have task to convert each alphabet to its ASCII value. Then find the nearest prime number of that ASCII value and return back the alphabet. But output string should be in **[a-zA-Z]** only.

**My code is :**

```
def find_next_prime(n):
    return find_prime_in_range(n, 2*n)

def find_prime_in_range(a, b):
    for p in range(a, b):
        for i in range(2, p):
            if p % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            return p
    return None
```

---

```
s = list(raw_input())
print "Given : ",s

asc = [ord(i) for i in s]
print "Ascii Values : ",asc

nearest_primes = [find_next_prime(x) for x in asc]
print 'Nearest_primes : ',nearest_primes

asc = [chr(i) for i in nearest_primes]
print "Final output : ",''.join(asc)
```

**Output I got :**

```
AFREEN
Given :  ['A', 'F', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N']
Ascii Values :  [65, 70, 82, 69, 69, 78]
Nearest_primes :  [67, 71, 83, 71, 71, 79]
Final output :  CGSGGO
```

**What I want :**

```
AFREEN
Given :  ['A', 'F', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N']
Ascii Values :  [65, 70, 82, 69, 69, 78]
Nearest_primes :  [67, 71, 83, 67, 67, 79]
Final output :  CGSCCO
```

So I have the problem in getting **smallest** and **nearest** prime number.

For number 69, both **67** ---69 ---**71** nearest prime numbers, but I need smallest of them. ie **67**

Here I have tried statically with `find_next_prime` method, but it's not the right way to do. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're looking for the prime number in the range `[n, 2n]`, wouldn't you want to looking in the range `[2, n)` as well?

Comment: @abacles no I need the prime number just near to n,so that the final output will be only of letters (a-zA-z) ,means no any other symbol other than Proper Alphabets

Comment: Then you can look in `[65, n)` and `(n, 90]` if it's uppercase or `[97, n)` and `(n, 122]` if it's lowercase.

Comment: This is a Hackerearth question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Basically you will iterate checking each value above and below, return the lower one first. You can make the prime function more efficient by only checking to the sqrt(a), as well as pre-computing the prime values.

```
def check_prime(a):
   for i in range(2, a):
      if a % i == 0:
         return False
   return True

def find_next_prime(n)
   # Not sure if you want this line or not
   # if check_prime(n):
   #   return n

   low = n - 1
   high = n + 1
   while True:
      if check_prime(low):
         return low
      elif check_prime(high):
         return high
      else:
         low -= 1
         high += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You never even consider 67. Your range iteration starts from 69, and only goes up Change the prime search range below.

```
def find_next_prime(n):
    return find_prime_in_range(n/2, 2*n) # you may go lower if you want
```

EDIT:

As it states in the comments, this will find the lowest prime from `n/2`. In case you really need the closest prime you need to measure the distance and chose the lowest from them.

Comment: @Shivkumar You would need to change your `find_prime_in_range()` so that it finds the closest to `n`, not `n/2` if you use this

Answer (score 2):

```
AFREEN
Given :  ['A', 'F', 'R', 'E', 'E', 'N']
Ascii Values :  [65, 70, 82, 69, 69, 78]
Nearest_primes :  [67, 71, 83, 67, 67, 79]
Final output :  CGSCCO
```

The E have a nearest prime lower. Take it into account. 
You must define a range below.

For example:

```
def find_prime_in_range(a, b):
    range_bt_a_b = b-a
    for dist in range(range_bt_a_b):
        upperElement = a+dist
        lowerElement = a-dist
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look for the next and previous numbers then choose the closest:

```
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        return n

def find_previous_prime(n):
    return find_next_prime(n, offset=-1)

def find_next_prime(n, offset = 1):
    p = n
    while p < 2 * n:
        p += 1 * offset
        if is_prime(p):
            break
    return p


p, n = find_previous_prime(69), find_next_prime(69))

print p if 69 - p < n - 69 else n
```

**output:**

```
67
```